# nftables philosophy, NTP synchronisation on a LAN

Tags: nftables

Given two machines `C` and `S`.
`C` and `S` are on the same `LAN 192.168.5.0/24`.
`C` needs to `NTP` synchronize onto `S`.
`S` has a `nftables` firewall.

Would someone be so very kind to explain to the beginner that I am,
the philosophy of `nftables` and in particular, what configuration is needed into the `S nftables` firewall to allow `NTP` traffic between `S` and `C` so that `C` can `NTP` synchronizes onto `S`.

```
table inet firewall 
{
   chain chain_input 
   {
   }

   chain iode_chain_forward 
   {
   }

   chain iode_chain_output 
   {
   }
}
```

Please note that this `NTP` synchronisation works properly without the firewall.

Is there any good `nftables` documentation available somewhere?